# An exception occurs during Evaluate Expression Action :

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio-3.0

I'm developing an application using kotlin on Android Studio and it gives me below error while trying to debug an object. I guess it only occurs while working with the old devices like samsung s3 which is running on 4.3 because it does not happen when I try to reproduce the same process with the other devices which run on 7.0 and 8.0. Anyone here who saw something like this before? Is it a bug or are config changes necessary that I'm unaware?

my kotlin version: 1.1.61

EDIT: I created a bug report https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69821974

[image: not working]
[image: working]

Comment: is it Resolved ?

Comment: It happened to me in Android 8.0